# The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, artisan

tengo un proyecto desarrollado en laravel 7, está alojado en un hosting compartido, necesito ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

el cron solo ejecuta scripts php.

Agregue en web.php

```
Route::get('/tarea', function() {
    Artisan::call('schedule:run');
});
```

cree un script con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
header ("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header ("Location: http://dominio/tarea");
exit();
?>
```

en el archivo config/flare.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],
```

en el log de laravel arroja el siguiente error:

The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

Alguien sabe como resolver este error?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP estás utilizando?

Comment: estoy utilizando php 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarás cambiar tu plan de hosting, para contratar un VPS o bien un servidor físico dedicado.

Hay ocasiones en las que los proveedores de hosting toman medidas de seguridad en planes compartidos, las cuales implican deshabilitar funciones como `exec`, `proc_open` o `system`.

Comment: Y si se permite una opinión personal, yo uso DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné, aunque quizá no sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, pero funciona.

Cree un controlador donde coloque la lógica que necesito y luego cree una tarea cron que ejecuta el siguiente script:

```
<?php
header ("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header ("Location: http://midominio.com/scheduleevent");
exit();
?>
```